# need help with numbering in libreoffice

Tags: libreoffice

I am making a document in Libre Office 4.4 ,please consider following situation:

```
1. this is the first item in main list
2. this is second but something is wrong
this is self made list (i dont want to number this list)
this is second item in self made list
1. i wanted 3. here but libre office gives me 1. :(
```

You might notice that the last list item should start as `3.` but instead it starts as `1.`
how to resolve this?

screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right clicking and in the menu select "Continue previous numbering"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm on my Windows machine(LO 4.4.1.2) right now, so this may not be the same, but when I indent (with the Tab button) my list, it does separate the second list and number them properly.

I do have to backspace the second list's numbers, but this looks like what you were asking for:

```
1. this is the first item in main list
2. this is second but something is wrong
      this is self made list (i dont want to number this list)
      this is second item in self made list
3. i wanted 3. here but libre office gives me 1.
```

Answer (score 0):

Odd - I just opened a new document, selected numbering on (F12), typed something, hit return, typed something, hit return, typed something hit return and got a 1), 2), 3) numbered list.

Maybe try a Reset for your numbering options - click down arrow next to the numbering icon, click more numbering in the drop down and you should see a numbering control panel with a reset button.

Comment: I also tried using F12 button but it starts from 1.

Answer (score 0):

Select *outline numbering*:

[image: LibreOffice 'Outline Numbered' dialog]

making your inner (custom) list at level 2 (right click -> "Down one level"); and then set the numbering for the second level to "None":

[image: LibreOffice 'Options' dialog]

Remember to also set the "After" character to empty, else there will be a stray period at the start of each custom list item.

Comment: pls see my screenshot sir

Answer (score 0):

This is another solution beside using right click > continue numbering:

1. this is the first item in main list
2. this is second but something is wrong

   this is self made list (i dont want to number this list) (use backspace to remove number)

   this is second item in self made list
3. here but libre office gives 1, turnOff numbering, then turnON numbering after this, Place your cursor on this line.